# Azure Functions - synchronization of trigger functions is not working

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

In this issue:

[Azure Functions - Event Hub not triggering Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850735/azure-functions-event-hub-not-triggering-functions)

I described a problem with syncing event hub triggers and I managed to find a solution by simply invoking 'syncfunctiontriggers' action with Azure CLI:

```
az resource invoke-action --resource-group <resourceGrouName> --action syncfunctiontriggers --name <functionAppName> --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites
```

Unfortunately this stopped working since 5th June and triggers are not fired on with messages getting into event hub - even if I call this command above. I need to go to portal and open function apps to sync them again but for me it is not a feasible solution.

I need to have an automated way of creating whole resource group, containing event hub, function apps, storages. At best with the use of Azure CLI.

Has anybody found a workaround for it or is this problem known already to Azure's team?

Comment: can you share your function app name either directly or indirectly https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately

Comment: sure, the function app name is dev1-save-to-storage.azurewebsites.net. But I guess you can reproduce it with any setup, simply create a resource group with CLI's: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-deployment-create , and then deploy function app's source with CLI's zip push deployment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-deployment-source-config-zip - the triggers won't be working until you enter them on portal

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I have found a workaround that is not entering the azure's portal. Simply make a call to trigger's function app page, e.g.:

```
curl -s https://<function-app-name>.azurewebsites.net > /dev/null
```

And after that if I run E2E tests, event hub triggers start to work. However, as with previous workarounds that I'd used, I don't how long it might be valid.